# How do I set Lotus Notes 5 as default mail program in Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, lotus-notes, email-client

I am trying to set Lotus Notes 5 as the default email client in Windows 7 Professional.

I have tried the steps outlined [at hwupgrade.it](http://www.hwupgrade.it/forum/showthread.php?t=2714396), but have had no luck. How can I set Lotus Notes 5 as my default email client.

Comment: Please describe the problem and all the steps you've taken so far right here in English, rather than expecting people to go visit some Italian forum. The question and answers should be on this site.

Comment: @rhsatrhs that's hardly constructive or relevant.

Comment: Perhaps not, but I made it a comment, not an answer because I knew that I wasn't addressing the question as the OP would have hoped. It would surprise me if something as old as Notes 5, which dates to to Windows 95 era, actually works properly as a default mail program under Windows 7. Did Windows even have that concept back then? It would even surprise me if anyone has tried this combination of versions to find out what works and what doesn't. My real suggestion to the OP has to be to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

from start menu select **default programs** and then select the option  **set your default programs**  choose lotus notes from the list in left pane and click on the option **set this program as default**